# Lipschitz functions and an equality $ f(x) = \inf_y \{ f(y) + kd(x,y) \}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $ f: M \to \mathbf{R}$ a $k$-Lipschitz function, i,e $ |f(x)-f(y)| \le k \cdot d(x,y) $ for every $x,y \in M$. Prove that   $ \forall x\in M$ :

$$
f\left( x \right) = \inf\limits_{y \in M}  \{{f\left( y \right) + k \cdot d\left( {x,y} \right)}\}  = \sup\limits_{y \in M} \{ {f\left( y \right) - k \cdot d\left( {x,y} \right)} \}.
$$
I have no idea how to prove this :/

Comment: The Module is not in the question, otherwise you are only considering positive functions!

Comment: yes you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have to suppose $ Start defining the functions H, G

$H(x)=\inf...$ and $G(x)=\sup...$ then first note that $H(x)\leq f(x)$ (just apply $ y=x$), then for the other inequality, consider $y_n$ such that $f(y_n)+kd(x,y_n)<H(x)+\frac{1}{n}$ then we have

$$f(x)=[f(x)-f(y_n)]-kd(x,y_n)+[f(y_n)+kd(x,y_n)]<|f(x)-f(y_n)|-kd(x,y_n)+H(x)+\frac{1}{n}<0+H(x)+\frac{1}{n}<H(x)+\frac{1}{n}$$

Since $n$ is arbitrary we get

$f(x)\leq H(x)$ ergo $f(x)=H(x)$.

The other equality is left as an exercise!